# Asset checkbox not eveluating to true in testclass

Tags: apex, unit-test, formula-field, inputcheckboxes

I have a checkbox on asset which should turn true by the following formula:

```
IF( 
ISPICKVAL( Product2.Bedrijf__c , ""D S" ) && Eind_datum__c >= TODAY() || 
ISPICKVAL( Product_2__r.Bedrijf__c , "D S" ) && Eind_datum__c >= TODAY() || 
ISPICKVAL( Product_3__r.Bedrijf__c , "D S" ) && Eind_datum__c >= TODAY() || 
ISPICKVAL( Product_4__r.Bedrijf__c , "D S" ) && Eind_datum__c >= TODAY() || 
ISPICKVAL( Product_5__r.Bedrijf__c , "D S" ) && Eind_datum__c >= TODAY() , 
TRUE , FALSE )
```

I checked how to make the check box true by adding a product the only required fields on product are Name and Bedrijf__c = 'D S'

In my Tesclass I made the following which should return the checkbox to true on asset but my debug returns false.

Am I missing something in my code? See below:

```
Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Testproduct', IsActive = true , Bedrijf__c = 'D S', Onderhoud_op_product__c =true );
insert prod;

List<Asset> asst = new List<Asset>();
for(Integer i=0;i<100;i++) {
    Asset a = new Asset(Name='TestAsset' + i, Accountid = accts[i].Id, Eind_datum__c = system.TODAY() +100, Product2 = prod );
    asst.add(a);
}
insert asst;  
System.debug(asst[0].Design_Solutions_Product__c);
```

Comment: Can you try to check by querying the record using `asst.Id` and then debug? Like `Asset a = [SELECT Id, Design_Solutions_Product__c FROM Asset WHERE ID = :asst[0].Id];  System.debug(a.Design_Solutions_Product__c);`

Comment: @HemantJain asst[0].Id gives me an Id, and the above suggested returns false

Comment: Try debugging all the variables required in the formula. `Product2.Bedrijf__c` , `Eind_datum__c` to check if there is any other process changing these field's value

Comment: @HemantJain the only thing I see with the debugging is that Eind_datum__c =   2018-07-14 00:00:00 instead of 2018-07-14

Comment: @HemantJain seem like the formulafield is reevalueated on insert and does not have the actuel value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `insert` DML does not by itself populate formula fields. You need to either query desired fields from your inserted record (other than Id) to obtain their values, or call the sObject method [`recalculateFormulas`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Note that the latter approach does not work for cross-object formulas, for which you must query the object. Since you do have cross-object formulas, you need to perform a query for the fields whose values you want to check.

Comment: Isn't the query suggested by   Hemant Jain doing the same? This still returns false.